# angular.min.js:92 Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I develop Angularjs application with php backend. I got error like this

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/unpr?p0=constantsProvider%20%3C-onstants%20%3C-%20userService
    at http://localhost/Security/libs/js/angular.min.js:6:450
    at http://localhost/Security/libs/js/angular.min.js:36:202
    at Object.c [as get] (http://localhost/Security/libs/js/angular.min.js:34:305)
    at http://localhost/Security/libs/js/angular.min.js:36:270
    at c (http://localhost/Security/libs/js/angular.min.js:34:305)
    at d (http://localhost/Security/libs/js/angular.min.js:35:6)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost/Security/libs/js/angular.min.js:35:165)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost/Security/libs/js/angular.min.js:35:435)
    at Object.d [as invoke] (http://localhost/Security/libs/js/angular.min.js:35:36)
    at http://localhost/Security/libs/js/angular.min.js:36:288
```

and my controller

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('smss').controller('loginController', ['$scope','userService','$http', loginController]);

function loginController($scope,userService, $http) {
    $scope.data = {email: '', password: ''};

    // login function 
    $scope.login = function (data) {

        // user auth data 
        var authData = {
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password,
            id: 1
        }

        userService.authUser(authData).success(function(){       
            }).error(function(){
              $scope.data = {email : '',password : ''};
            })

      }

  }

})();
```

and my service class like below

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('smss').service('userService', ['$http','constants', userService]);

    function userService($http,constants) {
        return {
            checkUser: function(data){
                return $http.post(constants.SERVER_URL+ '/api/checkUser',data);
            },
            newUser: function(data){
                return $http.post(constants.SERVER_URL+ '/api/newUser',data);
            },
            authUser: function(data){  
                $http.post('api/authUser.php', data).success(function (data) {
                        console.log(data);

                });
                return $http.post(constants.SERVER_URL+ '/api/authUser',data); 
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

and **constants**

```
(function() {
     "use strict";
    angular.module('smss').constant('constants', {
        SERVER_URL: 'http://localhost/security/'
    })
})();
```

Why, I got error like this? how i solve it? there **userService** , I want to add my controller but i got error below.

I want send $http post requst to my php file but I try to get like this way.

Comment: forgot to inject $http in controller

Comment: angular.module('smss').controller('loginController', ['$scope','userService' ,Here '$http'

Comment: Have you added path of constants.js in your html?

Answer (score 1):

Thye problem is you are not injecting $http properly. you forgot to add $http.

```
angular.module('smss',[]);// You must need to declare module this way.
```

Than,

```
angular.module('smss').controller('loginController', ['$scope','userService','$http', loginController]);

 function loginController($scope,userService, $http) {}
```

Comment: Post you complete code. You just posted your controller code.

Comment: what is "constants" in dependency. It seems error is bcoz of that.

Comment: angular.module('smss',[]); add my app.js

Comment: Have you added path of constants.js in your html?